# Intensity of Compton scattering photons

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, scattering, radiation

In various sources ([1](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Normalized-intensity-distribution-for-Compton-scattered-K-REC-radiation-I-I-90-as_fig3_6643365), [2](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_University_Physics_%28OpenStax%29/University_Physics_III_-_Optics_and_Modern_Physics_%28OpenStax%29/06%3A_Photons_and_Matter_Waves/6.04%3A_The_Compton_Effect), [3](https://www.physics.brocku.ca/PPLATO/h-flap/phys10_1.html), [4](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/compdat.html), to name a few) I have seen this graph shown below, that shows how *intensity* depends on the wavelength of the scattered photon $\lambda'$.

[image]

Now, I do understand what this graph shows conceptually: front-scattered photons preserve most of it's energy, so $\lambda'=\lambda_0$, and as the scattering angle increases from 0°to 180° (back-scattering), photon loses part of it's original energy so the energy of scattered photon is smaller (i.e. wavelength is larger $\lambda'>\lambda_0$).

What I don't understand is: how is *intensity* found analytically in this case?
My guess is that these graphs are a depiction of experimental results, and intensity is being measured by detectors placed at certain angles.

But, also, I guess that there must be an analytical way to express this intensity, so that when it is graphed for certain $\theta$, it shows a pattern as seen in the picture above.

I tried using Planck's radiation intensity formula combined with $\Delta\lambda=\frac{h}{mc}(1-\cos\theta)$, but it didn't meet with the graphs above.

So my question is: how is intensity expressed analytically as a function of $\theta$ and $\lambda'$ in the case of Compton scattering?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Nishina_formula

Answer (score 0):

Intensity depends on number of photons.

1. lambda0 is received on collision with atom
2. lambda` is received on collision with electron

xray photons have energies of 17 KeV and the bound state energies of carbon
are about 300 eV. There are more free electrons (valence + loosely bound) as compared to number of atoms.Thats why the second peak is higher.

reference : https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-04-quantum-physics-i-spring-2016/f928b8dce3d6a218fddda9617c5eb4f2_MIT8_04S16_LecNotes3.pdf